# sql loader error, can't open file

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I am using Oracle to read csv file. Here is my code in ctl file:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\...\TEST2.csv'
APPEND
INTO TABLE TEST2
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
   NAME CHAR;
   CLASS CHAR;
   SCORE INT;
)
```

It should be simple. But I got the error like "can't open file TEST2.csv".
However, the file is there. What to please?

Comment: make sure you have the correct permission

Comment: Thank you for all your reply. I am working on my own machine. The exact error message is "SQL*Loader-500: can't open file (c:\...\test2.csv) . I am working on windows. The csv file is not read-only file. How to check permission please?

Comment: If you can open the file as the same user your're running SQL\*Loader as then the permissions seem to be OK. The most likely issue is that you have the path slightly wrong, which I'm sure you've checked and verified (copying from the control file and pasting into the start->run box, for example), and which we can't verify of course (even for obvious typos since you've obscured it).

Comment: Thanks for all your answer.